# Pycharm save Python console commands to a file without using iPython or Jupyter

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to be able to save all my terminal commands to a history file while using Pycharm.  I understand this is possible using the, "External Tools," option in the IDE settings.  Does anyone have a FAQ or setup instruction set for how to do this?

Note per duplication mark: Yes, I could use Jupyter or iPython, but I believe what I want is far simpler than either solution and would not require me to put those packages into my project.  I'm looking for a simple output of my terminal commands to a file for copy / paste.  Additionally, Jupyter and iPython both seem to require (for their latest versions) I upgrade beyond Python 2.7, which I'm currently using. So I'm not sure the question is a duplicate.

Thanks much.

Comment: Actually, after looking at all of them closely, they don't.  I'm looking for a pycharm-specific implementation, and all the answers in that question refer specifically to saving your Python commands.  The Pycharm terminal is a virtual-environment bounded shell that can include running Python but is not the same thing as an interactive Python prompt.

Comment: You're right, this is a more specific question. Upvoted and my original comment removed.